# Resizable button with an image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I want to create a button like this one :

[image]

but bigger, resizable and to function properly on bootstrap.

Here's what I've done so far:

[image]

I've tried with `display: inline-block;` on `download-btn-icon` and `download-btn-text` then I wanted to center the `.fa` using http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/ but the `.fa` displays way out of `download-btn`.

This is the html:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <div class="download-btn">
        <div class="download-btn-icon">
            <i class="fa fa-cloud-download fa-3x"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="download-btn-text">
            <h3>Download Client</h3>
            <h5>Get the latest full updated client.</h5>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the less:

```
.download-btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #000;

  .download-btn-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;

    .fa{
      padding-top: 14px;
      padding-left: 23px;
    }
  }

  .download-btn-text {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 75%;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }
}
```

I'm clueless I don't know how to align the divs properly, I need some advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`display: table-cell`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display#Values) and [`vertical-align: middle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) to achieve this effect. This solves the alignment issue and forces both elements to have the same height.

```css
h3, h5 {
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}
.download-btn-icon,
.download-btn-text {
    display: table-cell;
    background: #222;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 7.5px 15px;
    color: #999;
}
.download-btn-icon {
    border-right: 1px solid #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="download-btn">
    <div class="download-btn-icon">
        <i class="fa fa-cloud-download fa-3x"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="download-btn-text">
        <h3>Download Client</h3>
        <h5>Get the latest full updated client.</h5>
    </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```